# Using different joomla template for articles not assigned to menu

Tags: joomla, content-management-system

I am using a module that displays latest article posts. I am using 2 templates , one for the homepage and the other called templatePage for the other pages. 
The problem is that articles not assigned to menu when clicked display using the homepage template instead of templatePage.
Is there a way to assign this articles to the templatePage?

Comment: What version of Joomla are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if exists other option but you could set these articles to a menu and then hide the parent with `display:none;`. You will need a menu, like `article holder`, and just set the css.

This is ugly but probably the easy way.

Comment: That could work but the problem is the users wont be able to remember this every time they post an article. Currently am doing if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault($lang->getTag())) {
if(strpos($myCurrent ,'/index/') !== false )) reaquire("page.php") else require("home.php");
} Where $myCurrent is current url I was hoping joomla has a better way of doing it.

Comment: @jmsiox You define a static css to affect the main menu. If the main menu is a list category type, your problem is solved. The user only need to remember to set each article to a specific category. Anyway, is a good practice set a parent category holder to all articles.